# Invalid Syntax Error Script

Tags: python

Me and my friends  made a bot to play a game but when we try to run it, it says Invalid Syntax. We don't know too much in Python and I wanted to ask someone more experienced.
Here is the script :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    POINT p;
    POINT coords[4];
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    printf("Move cursor to following tiles and press enter to select the coordinates:\n\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%i. tile:", (i+1));
        getchar();
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        coords[i] = p;
        printf("- X: %d, Y: %d\n\n", p.x, p.y);
    }

    COLORREF currColor;
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    while(true) {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
            printf("\rPaused, press ENTER to continue ...");
            getchar();
            printf("Continue ...\n\n");
        }
        bool countFound = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, coords[i].x, coords[i].y);


            if(color <= 3000000) {
                printf("\r");

                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    printf("[ ] ");
                }
                printf("[X] ");
                for(int j = 0; j < (3-i); j++) {
                    printf("[ ] ");
                }

                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                SetCursorPos(coords[i].x, coords[i].y);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                if(color > 100000) {
                    Sleep(50);
                } else {
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: That's C++, not Python. No wonder you're getting syntax errors...

Comment: That is not a Python script, it is C++.  Small wonder it doesn't work under Python.

Comment: *`"Me and my friends made a bot"`* No you didn't. You downloaded some random code from the internet without even understanding *what language it was written in* and blindly tried to run it. That is how you spread viruses and destroy your computer. Please learn from this little episode - not all code online is what it says it is.

Comment: Also, to add a bit to what @MattDMo has already said, this really doesn't even _look_ like code for a bot. This looks like graphics related code. You all should really be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Python. This is actually C++ code. You didn't post the error, so I have to assume that you tried to execute this code as Python, which would obviously be your problem. If you called it Python by mistake, and actually got a C++ error, please post the error.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Sure! If you're problem is solved, be sure to mark this as the correct answer so people know the question is closed.